# Excel - Convert String with if condition to a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'd like to use something like the EVALUATE-Function in Excel for if-statements.

I've got the following issue: I'd like to use Excel to validate my data. I've got three sheets:

1. the real data I'd like to check. Each row represents a customer and each column some data. The columns have specific names like “age”, “name”, …
2. the description of the checks I’d like to perform. Each row represents one check and I’ve got 3 columns: 1 check_id – an identifier of each check; 2 check_desc – a description of the check that every normal person can understand like “Age below 18”; 3 rule – the Excel Formula as a string like If(age<18, “error”, “no error”)
3. the place where sheet 1 and 2 should come together. Each row should represent one customer and each column one check.

Now, if I’ve got for example check_1 “If(age<18, “error”, “no error”)” and the customer data 10 and 20, then the check for the first customer should fire and the check for the second shouldn’t.
If the data is changed, and the age is set from 10 to 18, then everything should be fine, or if the rule is changes to “If(age<21, “error”, “no error”)” then the new condition should be applied to all data.

Is something like this possible?
With the evaluate function only ‘simple’ formulas work.

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Attached you can find the 
[Excel-Sample File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10095862/validate_data.xlsx)

Comment: its not clear what your trying to achieve,  just make 1 sheet and have 1 column for checks, 3 ifs in the same function denoting an error in the row,

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely need some VBA here. Make a custom `EVAL` function:

```
Public Function EVAL(ByRef Rng As Range, Formula As String) As Variant
    Dim RngAddress As String
    RngAddress = "'" & Rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & Rng.Address(External:=False)
    EVAL = Evaluate(Replace(Formula, "$", RngAddress))
End Function
```

Then you can easily evaluate your values with formulas passed as text (`$` is for parameter):

```
=EVAL(A1, "IF($<21,""error"",""no error"")")
```

(note the escaped double quotes). But you would rather pass formula from another cell - then you can specify formula in cell with single quotes:

```
IF($<21,"error","no error")
=EVAL(A1, B1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But what do I have to do, if I've got multiple variables?

Comment: If this approach for single variable is okay for you I could modify it to handle multiple variables.

Comment: My goal was to write the condition as a text so that veryone can read and understand it. That's why I prefered to use named ranges like age. I'd would be great if I could wirte as a text age<18 and this would be evaluated, or AND(age>10, age<18). For the first, easy example the simple EVAL function works. But for the second it always shows false and if I enter the formula with = it's correct... Strange...

Answer (score 0):

I personally would rename check_desc!B2 to "Check_1" (*named range*) and then refer to that. You can use the INDIRECT function as well once you've renamed your column header "Check_1" as well. 
Note: the value in this case should be "18" instead of "age below 18". You can of course change the number format to *"age below "0*.
If the relations are changing too I would insert a table that would have uniform formulae changing in each cell when changed in one cell.

The only issue you would then face is the non-expanding nature of your table. You can use VBA for this, but maintaining formulae increases your accountability even if it would be slightly easier not to deal with nasty nested functions.